# cassandra setup - uneven load - what did I do wrong?

Tags: cassandra

For the sake of understanding I setup a 4 node cluster using the latest/greatest(released) version of Cassandra. The four nodes were brought up in sequence using almost entirely default settings and seem to be communicating properly.

I then created a schema as follows:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE first WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '1'
};
```

Create a simple table with 5 columns and added ~100K rows of data. All well and good. Data is available from every client so I'm thinking it's evenly spread about.

So I'm looking into a backup strategy and starting to mess about with snapshots and so forth. After running `nodetool snapshot` on each machine I want to know what it created. I go to the first machine and look in **/var/lib/cassandra/data/first** and see that it's empty. Hmm.. second machine.. same thing.. third.. finally on the 4th machine I see files in the data folder and a snapshot directory.

Running `nodetool ring` shows that each system *owns* roughly 25% but the *load* is heavily biased towards the one system that (seems to have) ended up with all the data.

Is all the data truly on this one machine? What step did I miss in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra assigns **token range** to each node in the cluster.

Since there are 4 nodes in your configuration, 25% of tokens are assigned to each node.

Every **insert query** will have a hash generated for that row data. The hash will always belong to **one and only one** of the token ranges, so this row data is stored in that particular physical node.

In your case , mostly the insert queries have same or similar partition key leading to the same physical node i.e. node 4.

For more details, watch [datastax website explaining partitioning.](http://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials/partitioning-and-replication)